# How to comment label in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I want to comment out the label of an ARM assembly code because I want to play with different codes, but even if I comment out the main label, the compiler still complains that the label is already defined.

Here's the code

```
.section    .data                


.section    .init                
.globl     _start                

_start:                          
    b       main                 

.section    .text                
main:                            
    mov     sp, #0x8000          
    mov     r1, #1               
    mov     r2, #3               
    sub     r1, r2               
halt$:                           
    b   halt$                    

.section    .data                

; STARTING FROM THIS, IT IS SUPPOSED TO BE COMMENTED OUT                             
;.section    .init               
;.globl     _start               

;_start:                         
    ;b       main                

;.section    .text               
;main:                           
    ;mov     sp, #0x8000         
    ;bl      EnableJTAG          

    ;mov     r1, #0              
    ;mov     r2, #0              
    ;mov     r3, #0  ;i = 0      

;forloop:                        
    ;cmp     r3, #100            
    ;bpl     forloopEnd          

    ;tst     r3, #0xAA           
    ;bne     elseif
```

Here's the error received

```
Error: symbol `_start' is already defined     
Error: symbol `main' is already defined       
Error: symbol `halt$' is already defined
```

So what can I do to let the compiler ignore the commented label? Thanks

Comment: Which assembler is this? Keil? GNU assembler?

Comment: If it is GNU assembler try using `#` instead of `;` . In GNU ARM assembler `;` is a statement separator, `#` is a line comment character

Comment: @MichaelPetch: In ARM syntax, `@` is the preferred comment character (and works on all ARM assemblers, not just gas).  `#` is part of the syntax (e.g. in `ADCS  R1, R3, ROR #0x18`), but apparently still works as a comment character in gas, too, when used before an instruction.  But `add r1, r2   # foo` gives *Error: garbage following instruction*.  `;` is still the gas statement separator, though, which is the problem here.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I'm aware of that, but I mentioned the `#` in this case because he was commenting out entire lines. I did say `#` is a **line comment**

Comment: If was using GCC to preprocess `.S` files I moight have even mentioned using `#if` statements

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I haven't looked at a lot of ARM asm.  Is it common for people / projects to actually use `#` for line-comments, instead of using the same comment character everywhere?  I had just assumed that you were "supposed" to just get used to using `@` everywhere, but `#` does look nice for line comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's an interesting question. I have seen developers who have done GNU Assembler on x86 and then got into ARM development - and they often producing function documentation at the top of a function by using `#`. I have a feeling for some it might be what they are more use to. This is usually why companies have coding guidelines and styles.

Comment: Personally I think `@` looks strange for a comment (although it is more universal for usage on ARM) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The `@` character denotes the start of a single-line comment when using GNU's ARM assembler for 32 bit source:

> The presence of a `@' anywhere on a line indicates the start of a comment that extends to the end of that line.
>
> If a `#' appears as the first character of a line then the whole line is treated as a comment, but in this case the line could also be a logical line number directive (see Comments) or a preprocessor control command (see Preprocessing).

([source](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars))

This is not true for 64 bit source. gas has horrible documentation for all processors (one size fits all(,so it is hard to comment on what it can and cannot do.

There may not be a way to comment out a single line in 64 bits **gas**. The output of the **-S** in **gcc** carefully avoids any comment lines, which is in IMO a bad sign.

This is the **as** I refer to on a 64 bit armbian:

```
 as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28
```

If confirmed, this could be considered a defect ("bug") and worth a bugreport.

Comment: In practice, `#` actually works after whitespace or labels, as long as its before any statement / directive, in gas 2.25.1.

Comment: @ is comment apparantly only for 32 bits GNU, not for the 64 bits GNU ARM assembler. # is not usable as a comment character because it plays a role in assembler statements.

Comment: The gnu tools refer to 64 bit arm as aarch64 and treat it as a totally seperate architecture. The documentation for comments in aarch64 gnu assembler can be found at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dChars.html and says to use //

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I solved this problem by using block comment /**/

```
.section    .data                


.section    .init                
.globl     _start                

_start:                          
    b       main                 

.section    .text                
main:                            
    mov     sp, #0x8000          
    mov     r1, #1               
    mov     r2, #3               
    sub     r1, r2               
halt$:                           
    b   halt$                    

.section    .data                

/*
STARTING FROM THIS, IT IS SUPPOSED TO BE COMMENTED OUT                             
.section    .init               
.globl     _start               
    _start:                         
    b       main                

.section    .text               
main:                           
    mov     sp, #0x8000         
    bl      EnableJTAG          

    mov     r1, #0              
    mov     r2, #0              
    mov     r3, #0  ;i = 

forloop:                        
    cmp     r3, #100            
    bpl     forloopEnd          

    tst     r3, #0xAA           
    bne     elseif
    ...
*/
```

Comment: Block comment is a bad idea in assembler, so I would certainly hope for a better solution.